# UNC path for windows service not accessible

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, remote-access, windows-services, unc

I have a remote directory that a web application accesses via a UNC path e.g. `\\192.168.0.42\g$\files`.

The web app runs on Tomcat which is being run as a Windows service i.e. no user is logged in.

I can access the directory when logged in as a user; and the web application can also access it when I start tomcat from a script; but if I start tomcat as a Windows service then it can't access the directory.

Can anyone suggest why the service can't access the remote path?

Comment: Most likely your problem is the service is running as a system user, and not a network user or a user on the remote machine. In a domain you would want to either allow everyone / anon users too, or preferable create a service account on the domain / network and run the service as that account

Comment: @AthomSfere Thanks... you've hit the nail on the head. I've reworded my question so you can provide this as an answer. Please do so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an answer to the re-worded question:

Most likely your problem is the service is running as a system user, and not a network user or a user on the remote machine. In a domain you would want to either allow everyone / anon users too, or preferable create a service account on the domain / network and run the service as that account